# How do I change the bar colors in chart.js barcharts?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have created a barchart with chart.js but all the bars are grey colored.  How do I make them all blue?  Heres my code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: dates,
    datasets: [
      { 
        data: values
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

From reading the documentation it seems that I need to change the property: backgroundColor.  So there should be a line somewhere with something like:

```
backgroundColor: 'blue'
```

or something similar.  I haven't been able to find an answer to this and all the examples in the documentation are way more complicated than what I need.

Comment: Can you include your `values` object?

Answer (score 1):

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: dates,
    datasets: [
      { 
        backgroundColor: ["#0000FF"],
        data: values
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: that colors 1 of the bars blue but the rest are still grey

Comment: @William234234, please check docs (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-properties) and sample (http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/vertical.html)